# How to create a shortcut to run PHP code in Windows?

Tags: php, windows

I wrote some PHP to generate a single PDF file with multiple pages based on input from a Comma Seperated Values (.csv) file.

Someone who is not familiar with programming will be running the PHP very often to generate the PDF file. That person will be responsible for changing the CSV file before generating it.

I need to know how I can provide him/her a shortcut in Windows so that when he/she click it, the PHP should execute and produce the PDF file in a hardcoded path.

Comment: Are you running the PHP in a local Apache server or on a website?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a shortcut to the page, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/mypdf.php
```

You can even open the link with a specific browser by typing one of these as the shortcut location:

```
chrome http://www.example.com/mypdf.php
```

```
firefox http://www.example.com/mypdf.php
```

```
iexplore http://www.example.com/mypdf.php
```

[image: a]

Alternatively, if you're indeed running PHP as CLI-only, see @sectus' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an shortcut on file itself, or executive php bin. Check [Command Line PHP on Microsoft Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php).

Just create shortcut with `C:\PHP5\php.exe -f "C:\PHP Scripts\script.php" -- -arg1 -arg2 -arg3`, but it will be depended on locations. So you could create association with php files and just create shortcut to your script.

Or you could launch web-server ([php web-server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)) and put link to your script to favorites in browser.